# how to make conference call in windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, opennetcf

could anyone please guide me how to make a conference call from netcf... in Windows Mobile
like i have three numbers and i want to dail them for a conference call...

Comment: It might help to talk about the *device* - as it will probably require device-specific servics; after all, xbox runs CF... and isn't a 'phone.

Comment: thanks Marc its added as Windows Mobile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done this myself, but you will have to use the [Telephony API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa922068.aspx).

You will find in there functions like:

[lineSetupConference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918927.aspx), 
[lineAddToConference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa918522.aspx), 
etc

I would recommend that you read the MSDN sections very closely as TAPI is not very easy to use.

I'm not sure how much access you have with C# and would also recommend that the coding around using these be done in C/C++ and you could expose them in a more simplified API via a DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dial three numbers at the same time on a Windows Mobile device. It probably has only one sim card (two at most if it is a dual-sim device).

Usually conference calls are managed by third parties or some kind of phone server that allows multiple people to dial in.

Comment: some companies allows mutli number or con calls.. so if you have such service enabled than what is the scenario?

Comment: Good point, I didn't realize that this was the case. Then I think the TAPI answer might be a good one.